# C++ Syntax Error - Cannot Identify Issue

Tags: c++, vector, syntax-error

I am new to C++ and having some trouble understanding the behaviour of it as it is quite different from the other languages I have studied.

Could someone please point me in the right direction to fix this code and explain the error logs?

I am using http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php to compile and run this code.

An array(vector) variable is declared of size 5, and then a for loop inside of a while loop will fill it and change the values. On the first loop of the while, the for loop fills it, if the first value entered is -1 the while loop should stop. Otherwise keep allowing the user to change the values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> items(5); 

    do
    {
        cout << "Type customer details: " << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "info " << 0 << ": ";

            items[i] >> cin;
        }

        int newBalance = items[1] + items[2] - items[3];

        if(newBalance > items[4])
        {
            cout << items[0] << " - " << items[4] << " - " << newBalance << " - Credit limit exceeded." << endl;
        }

    }while(items[0] != -1);
}
```

Error Log:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:13: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'int' and     'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}')
items[i] >> cin;
^
main.cpp:18:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/string:53:0,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/ios_base.h:41,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/ios:42,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/ostream:38,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:39,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note:     template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&     std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&,     std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note: template     argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:879:0,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:40,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/istream.tcc:955:5: note: template<class     _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&     std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s)
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/istream.tcc:955:5: note: template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:879:0,
from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:40,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/istream.tcc:923:5: note: template<class     _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&     std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/istream.tcc:923:5: note: template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:40:0,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:727:5: note: template<class     _Traits>     std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char,     _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char& __c)
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:727:5: note: template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:40:0,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:732:5: note: template<class _Traits>     std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char,     _Traits>&, signed char&)
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char& __c)
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:732:5: note: template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:40:0,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:774:5: note: template<class _Traits>     std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char,     _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char* __s)
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:774:5: note: template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/iostream:40:0,
from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:779:5: note: template<class _Traits>     std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char,     _Traits>&, signed char*)
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char* __s)
^
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:779:5: note: template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:16: note: mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>' and 'int'
items[i] >> cin;
^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

```
#include <vector>
```

see [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) online page

```
items[i] >> cin;  // this line is not valid
```

should be

```
std::cin >> item[i];
```

Or you call `std::getline` from console, convert to int then assign value to element in vector.

Comment: Probably, you want - `cin >> items[i];` instead.

Comment: @Mahesh I don't think there's any probably about it.

Comment: Checking this now, taking a while for the code to compile on the site cause of a heavy load apparently...

Comment: The code runs however it's just printing out:

"info 0: info 0: info 0: info 0: info 0: Type customer details: "

So something is wrong with the loop not waiting for input?

Comment: @AndrewB how do you mean just printing out?

Comment: it has gone into the loop of printing that to screen, it doesn't wait for me to enter input. And that is using codepad.org

Comment: It's probably just how codepad works, there's no more errors so I'll assume it works properly were it to have input values.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
items[i] >> cin;
```

with

```
cin >> items[i];
```